# Accessing JSON Array Data in React.js/Next.js Combo

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

Given an API which returns JSON data like:

```
["posts": 
    {"id":1,
     "name":"example",
     "date":"exampledate",
     "content":"examplecontent",
     "author":"exampleauthor"},
    {"id":2,
 ..]
```

The length of the array is unknown.

I am fetching data via isomorphic-fetch like this:

```
displayPosts.getInitialProps = async function() {
const res = await fetch('.../post');
const data = await res.json();
  return{
    posts: data.posts
  }
}
```

which is working (console.log.stringify(data)).

Now i want to display such posts on my displayPosts page.
Therefore i am using the following React Component.

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  stat = {
  // here i don't know how to set the state
}

  render() {
    return (
      // i want to render the data here
    );
  }
}
```

export default Posts;

**Question**: How do i set a state, so that i can neatly display every post in my displayPosts.js page with

```
<Posts posts={props.Posts}/>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
  state = {
      posts: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.savePosts();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      this.savePosts();
  }

  savePosts = () => {
      if(this.props.posts){
         //do any other processing here first if you like
         this.setState({
             posts: this.props.posts
         });
     }
  }
```

You probably don't *need* to save the posts in state, since you could just pull them from props directly. But if you need to process or transform them somehow, it might make sense.

In either case, you just hook into the lifecycle methods to do this.

Note: This will set the state every time the component updates. Often you only want to update the state when that specific prop changes. If so, you can first compare the old and new props to see if it has changed in a way that means you want to update your state.